# mssql hierarchy one row to multiple column query

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy

I have a table with structure and record like this

```
________________________________________
ID          | Name              |
-----------------------------------------
01          | Group Category    |
0101        | Category      |
010101      | Category Sub      |
01010101    | Category Sub Sub  |
-----------------------------------------
```

How to make a query result with mssql like bellow.

```
Column1         | Column2       | Column3       | Column4           |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group Category  | Category Sub  | Category Sub  | Category Sub Sub  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (ID varchar(10),name varchar(20))
insert into @t (ID,name) values ('01','Group Category'),('0101','Category'),
('010101','Category Sub'),('01010101','Category Sub Sub ')



select 
MAX(case when ID = '01' THEN name ELSE '' END )AS Column1,
MAX(case when ID = '0101' THEN name ELSE '' END )AS Column2,
MAX(case when ID = '010101' THEN name ELSE '' END )AS Column3,
MAX(case when ID = '01010101' THEN name ELSE '' END )AS Column4 
from @t
```

Comment: thank @mohan111 for u solution, it works. But if the ID is dynamic like '0101 => Category', '010102 => Category Sub Two' etc, the result can't display another record it's just show one result.

Comment: example this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793622/mssql-hierarchy-one-row-to-multiple-column-query

Answer (score 0):

You could also PIVOT your table like this:

```
SELECT [1] AS Column1, [2] AS Column2, [3] AS Column3, [4] AS Column4
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) Seq 
    FROM [Table]
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Name)
    FOR Seq IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) p
```