# SQL Server hierarchy one row to multiple column query

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I have a table with structure and record like this

```
ID          | Name                      |
-----------------------------------------
01          | Group Category            |
0101        | Category One              |
010101      | Category One Sub          |
01010101    | Category One Sub Sub      |
010102      | Category One Sub Two      |
01010201    | Category One Sub Sub Two  |
0102        | Category Two              |
010201      | Category Two Sub          |
01020101    | Category Two Sub Sub      |
0103        | Category Three            |
010301      | Category Three Sub        |
01030101    | Category Three Sub Sub    |
-----------------------------------------
```

How to make a query result with SQL Server like below.

```
Column1         | Column2       | Column3               | Column4                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group Category  | Category One  | Category One Sub      | Category One Sub Sub      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group Category  | Category One  | Category One Sub Two  | Category One Sub Sub Two  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group Category  | Category Two  | Category Two Sub      | Category Two Sub Sub      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group Category  | Category Three| Category Three Sub    | Category Three Sub Sub    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you able to amend the structure of your table to include a parent id?

Comment: @ChrisPickford could you give me some example with parent id? thank's a lot.

Comment: I think you would need ParentID - ID relationship in table(now there's none), Levels and then to do dynamic pivoting (unless you know maximum depth possible).

Comment: Could you give as some examples of what you have tried so far and what's not working exactly?

Comment: Example of your table with a parent ID: `CREATE TABLE [Test] ([Id] INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Name] VARCHAR(30), [ParentId] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Test]([Id]))`

Comment: Write a select that gets a column4 value on each row, and use sub-selects to get the other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With table structure as shown, and if number of levels is fixed, you can simply self join multiple times using LIKE on ID column as a join condition:

```
select t1.name, t2.name, t3.name, t4.name
from #t t4
join #t t3 on t4.id like t3.id+'__'
join #t t2 on t3.id like t2.id+'__'
join #t t1 on t2.id like t1.id+'__'
```

This should give you the desired output.